# how to add subscript in asp boundfield header text

Tags: c#, asp.net, subscript, boundfield

I want headername to be CO<sub>2</sub> with 2 as subscript 
this is my code.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CO2" HeaderText="CO2" />
```

so far i tried

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CO2" HeaderText="CO<sub>2</sub>" />
```

but this did not work.

please suggest a way